# Vue.js: check if a component exists

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I need to do some stuff in the `ready:` of the root instance only when some components don't exist (they weren't declared in the HTML).

How can I check if a component exists?

Comment: try `v-ref`, https://vuejs.org/api/#v-ref, `<comp v-ref:comp-name></comp>`,  `if (this.$refs.compName)`..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I really hope there is a better answer than this, but for the moment this solves the problem.

In the ready, I access the children elements through `this` (could be also `Vue`) and check whether their name is or not what I was expecting:

```
    ready: function() {

        for (var i = 0; i < this.$children.length; i++) {
            if (
                   this.$children[i].$options.name == 'my_component_a'
                || this.$children[i].$options.name == 'my_component_b'
                || this.$children[i].$options.name == 'my_component_c'
            ) {
                //do stuff
            }
        }
    }
```

You can also access them directly if you previously assigned them a reference in their template:
//template:

```
<comp v-ref:my_component_ref></comp>
```

Then from the Vue component ready:

```
if (this.$refs.my_component_ref){
//do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 19):

We can get the list of the loaded (global and/or local) components of a Vue instance from the instantiation options which is available through the [`vm.$options`](https://vuejs.org/api/#vm-options) where the `vm` is the current Vue instance.

`vm.$options` property holds the whole options of a Vue instance. For example `vm.$options.components` returns an object containing the loaded components of the current Vue instace `vm`.

However depending on the way how a component is registered, either globally through [`Vue.component()`](https://vuejs.org/guide/components.html#Registration) or [locally within a Vue instance options](https://vuejs.org/guide/components.html#Local-Registration), the structure of the `vm.$options.components` would be different.

If the component is registered globally, the component will be added to `vm.$options.components` [[Prototype]] linkage or its `__proto__`.

And if the component is registered locally within the Vue instance options, the component will be added to the `vm.$options.components` object directly as its own property. So that we do not have to walk the proto chain to find the component.

---

In the following example we will see how to access the loaded components in both situations.

Notice the `// [1]` and `// [2]` comments in the code which are related to local registered components.

```js
// the globally registered component
Vue.component('global-child', {
  template: '<h2>A message from the global component</h2>'
});

var localComponent = Vue.extend({ template: '<h2>A message from the local component</h2>' });


// the root view model
new Vue({
  el: 'body',
  data: {
    allComponents: [],
    localComponents: [],
    globalComponentIsLoaded: false
  },
  // local registered components
  components: { // [1]
    'local-child': localComponent
  },
  ready: function() {    
    this.localComponents = Object.keys(this.$options.components); // [2]
    
    this.allComponents = loadedComponents.call(this);
    this.globalComponentIsLoaded = componentExists.call(this, 'global-child');
  }
});

function loadedComponents() {
  var loaded = [];
  var components = this.$options.components;
  for (var key in components) {
    loaded.push(key);
  }
  return loaded;
}

function componentExists(component) {
  var components = loadedComponents.call(this);
  if (components.indexOf(component) !== -1) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/1.0.24/vue.js"></script>
<h1>A message from the root Vue instance</h1>
<p>All loaded components are: {{ allComponents | json }}</p>
<p>local components are: {{ localComponents | json }}</p>
<p><code>&lt;global-child&gt;</code> component is loaded: <strong>{{ globalComponentIsLoaded }}</strong></p>
<global-child></global-child>
<local-child></local-child>
```

Comment: I really appreciate your explanation, unfortunately doesn't fork for me. I want to know the components which are being used in the HTML. I made a little fiddle were I removed the <global-child> element in the HTML but it's still recognized as loaded: https://jsfiddle.net/ncmqhy5n/2/

Answer (score 11):

I'm not sure if you need a dynamic method, but this may help to determine if a component exists:

```
Vue.options.components['CompOne']
```

found:

https://github.com/vuejs/Discussion/issues/140

Answer (score 10):

To check if a global component exists:

```
let componentExists = 'componentName' in Vue.options.components
```

---

To check if a imported component exists in a component:

```
let componentExists = 'componentName' in this.$options.components
```

Answer (score 5):

get the current component imported components

```
this.$options.components[findComponentName]
```

get the global components

```
Vue.$options.components[findComponentName]
```

Comment: The global options are in `Vue.options` not `Vue.$options`.

Comment: @aaron are you check perfectly? it should be Vue.$options

Comment: https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/6fe07ebf5ab3fea1860c59fe7cdd2ec1b760f9b0/src/core/global-api/index.js#L54

Answer (score 3):

```
var isComponentExists = "component-name" in Vue.options.components
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/19931640)

Comment: @VinayPrajapati seems like a legit answer

Comment: Please explain a bit of what was wrong done by OP and how it solves the problem. One liners should be avoided.