# webpack, vue, nuxt - import component if file exist

Tags: vue.js, webpack, nuxt.js

I want to load component only if file exist.
Is there any way to achieve it?
I tried:

```
components: {
 MyComponent: () => import(
                    /* webpackMode: "lazy" */
                    /* webpackIgnore: true */
                    'themes/MyComponent'
                   ).catch(() => import('default/MyComponent'))
}
```

But despite of "themes/MyComponent" exist "default/MyComponent" is loaded.

If I set /* webpackIgnore: false */ and  delete "themes/MyComponent" then get

"Module not found: Error: Can't resolve "themes/MyComponent"

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the use case but is this, the solution that you're looking for ? https://forum.vuejs.org/t/how-to-check-if-path-of-file-exist/59345/3?u=kissu

```js
try {
  this.storyToRead = require('../assets/data/stories/' + this.storyFileName)
  // do something
} catch (e) {
  // do something else
}
```

Comment: There is no matter if i use import.catch or try/catch and import or require. I always get error. So "Try/catch" doesn't work.

Comment: Was it the use case for it ? Also, check this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37389788/vue-js-check-if-a-component-exists

Comment: I use in my app theme. 
If some component dosen't exist iny my theme i want to load "default" template. Right now webpack throws error for : 
if(1===2) { import(''PATH_TO_NON_EXISTING MODULE') }

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I came up with a solution :)
Basically I created files list using webpack and then I check if the file path includes in that list.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <Component :is="MyComponent" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  computed: {
    filesList() {
      const filesList = require
        .context('../components/', true, /.*\.vue$/)
        .keys()
      const itemsList = filesList.map((item) =>
        item.replace('.vue', '').slice(2)
      )
      return itemsList
    },
    path() {
      const filePath = 'MyComponent'
      return this.fileExists(filePath) ? filePath : 'Default'
    },
    MyComponent() {
      return () => import(`~/components/${this.path}`)
    },
  },
  methods: {
    fileExists(path) {
      return this.filesList.includes(path)
    },
  },
}
</script>
```